# How to update value in grid store data in extJS while loading the value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using extJSgrid where I am getting some boolean value. based on some those value I have to show yes and no. This I am able to through rendere. Now sometime in code I need value yes and no only so what I am doing is, I am updating the value while renderere only. But this is up the same value for all the gris in extJS.

Here in my code/

```
my column defention : 

    

{
            "text" : "my value",
            "dataIndex" : "colvalue",
            "flex" : 1.0,
            "renderer" : "renderValue"
        }
```

my Renderer method :

```
renderValue : function(value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView){
        let view = this.getView();
             if(!Ext.isEmpty(store)){
                rec = store.getData();
            }
            if(!Ext.isEmpty(rec)){
                if(!Ext.isEmpty(rec.items)){
                    var val = (value === 1) ?  "Yes" : "No";
                    store.getData().getAt(row).data.colvalue = val 
                }
            } 
        return ((value === 1) ?  ("Yes") : ("No") );
     },
```

this code is updating the value for all. Is there anyway I can update this.

Comment: Please correct your question. Where's the problem? Btw. i prefer to use new column definition in store `model` with some `convert` function instead of update in renderer. Update in renderer is bad idea.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what the goal is here, but I agree with @norbeq... you should create another field in your model definition and do this yes/no logic.  So maybe something like `{name: 'colValueDisplay', type: 'string', persist: false, depends: ['colvalue'], convert: function(value, record) { return record.get('colvalue') === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'; } }`

Comment: yes, but again this is changing the same value for all the record.